# Tabular environment within the \newenvironment

Tags: tables, environments

I'm writing a book, in which we refer the reader to the CD-ROM for the source code, and tell him the compiler and the result of running the program. Here's an example:

[image: expected]

Since this "template" is happening a lot in the book, I decided to define a new environment for it (the command `\cprotEnv` used below is from the package [cprotect](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cprotect)):

```
\newenvironment{CDROM}[2]
    {\begin{tabular}{| m{0.5in} m{0.3in} m{5in} |}
        \hline
        \includegraphics[width=0.5in]{CD-ROM.pdf} && #1 \\
        & \includegraphics[width=0.3in]{Hand.pdf} &
        We used the free compiler #2. \\
        & \includegraphics[width=0.3in]{Hand.pdf} &
    }
    {\\ \hline \end{tabular}}

\cprotEnv\begin{CDROM}{\verb"\SampleCodes\C++\GetPageSize"}{Open Watcom}
The page size for this system is 4096 bytes.
\end{CDROM}
```

However, the output is something peculiar:

[image: produced]

Could you please help me to get the expected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\cprotEnv` is thought for particular environments such as `align` that don't accept verbatim in their body. If your schemes are always like the example, with two "handed lines", it's easier to define a command rather than an environment:

```
\newcommand{\CDROM}[3]
    {\begin{tabular}{| m{0.5in} m{0.3in} m{5in} |}
        \hline
        \includegraphics[width=0.5in]{CD-ROM.pdf} && #1 \\
        & \includegraphics[width=0.3in]{Hand.pdf} &
        We used the free compiler #2. \\
        & \includegraphics[width=0.3in]{Hand.pdf} & #3\\ \hline \end{tabular}}
```

and then use it as

```
\cprotect[mmm]\CDROM{\verb"\SampleCodes\C++\GetPageSize"}{Open Watcom}
  {The page size for this system is 4096 bytes.}
```

A way that frees you from `\cprotect` is

```
\newcommand{\CDROM}{\begingroup\catcode`\#=12 \xCDROM}
\newcommand{\xCDROM}[3]
    {\begin{tabular}{| m{0.5in} m{0.3in} m{5in} |}
        \hline
    \includegraphics[width=0.5in]{CD-ROM.pdf} &&
          \ttfamily\catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\ =9
          \scantokens{#1} \\
        & \includegraphics[width=0.3in]{Hand.pdf} &
        We used the free compiler #2. \\
        & \includegraphics[width=0.3in]{Hand.pdf} & #3\\ \hline \end{tabular}\endgroup}
```

and now

```
\CDROM{\SampleCodes\C++\GetPageSize}{Open Watcom}
  {The page size for this system is 4096 bytes.}
\CDROM{\SampleCodes\C#\GetPageSize}{}{}
```

work without `\verb`. This, however, assumes that you don't need spaces in the "verbatim" first argument.

By splitting the command into two parts we can ensure that the `#` character is not doubled as it would happen if we added `` \catcode`\#=12 `` along with the other settings.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just one point: The second approach prints unwanted spaced and the command `\endinput`; i.e. instead of `\SampleCodes\C++\GetPageSize` it prints `\SampleCodes \C ++\GetPageSize \endinput`.

Comment: See edited answer; if you don't need spaces in that argument it's more practical.

Comment: Sorry, one more problem: If I try something like `\CDROM{\SampleCodes\C#\GetPageSize}{}{}`, I get an error related to the use of `#`. I can't escape it since the catcode of \ has changed. I can't change the catcode of `#` since I need it to define `#1`, `#2`, and `#3`. What can I do?

Comment: You find the new definition.